# Error when installing cmake via MacPorts

Tags: cmake, macports

I get this error while installing cmake on my machine.

> Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure:
>   shell command failed (see log for details) Error: Failed to install
>   cmake Log for cmake is at:
>   /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_cmake/cmake/main.log

The full log is [here](http://cl.ly/2I1P2D2S3X2O0l2g0p2e), but what I basically see is compilation errors.

I don't have any particular setup on my machine. Lion 10.7.3, Xcode 4.2.1 installed in the default directory.

I've tried to install it with multiple options (+universal), I also uninstalled MacPorts completely before retying. Always with the same issue.

Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and most serious error is this here:

```
:info:configure [...]/cmake-2.8.6/Source/cmFindProgramCommand.cxx:17:10: fatal error: 'CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h' file not found
:info:configure #include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
:info:configure          ^
```

It seems like your installation is incomplete as this header is supposed to be found at `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CoreFoundation.h` or in the corresponding platform SDK.

Try reinstalling Xcode from the App Store or [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).